# Posts in Custom postype not visible on frontpage wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type restaurant. But Its not coming on the main page. But I'm able to see the post in single view when using the permalink. Is it that I have to make any changes in the index.php? If yes what changes? I'm using the default Twenty Ten theme in wordpress 3.

And how can I get only the custom post type in another page with pagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use postmeta for this instead of messing with the post_type as there is wordpress functionality which is depended on post_type.

Comment: If you're still checking this, I just realized that in WP3 they added functionality to make creating custom post types easier. However, I have seen many users who still have problems with it, so I guess it's still a bit of a toss up.